# Get specified number of rows in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I want to get number of rows in SQL. I use

```
select ROWNUM,FULL_NAME
from OSQS_INSTITUTION
order by FULL_NAME
WHERE rownum BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

and try this

```
select ROWNUM,FULL_NAME
from OSQS_INSTITUTION
order by FULL_NAME limit 10,20
```

and both return the same error

> SQL command not properly ended

**EDIT:**

```
    StringBuilder sqlStatement = new StringBuilder();
    sqlStatement.append("SELECT USER_NO,FULL_NAME,ACTIVE from");
    sqlStatement.append("(");
    sqlStatement.append(" SELECT USER_NO,FULL_NAME,ACTIVE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY full_name) rn");
    sqlStatement.append("FROM osqs_institution");
    sqlStatement.append(")WHERE rn BETWEEN ? AND ? ");

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlStatement.toString());
    pstmt.setInt(1, from);
    pstmt.setInt(2, to);
    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

with required try and catch.

Comment: I know where is the error, in this line  sqlStatement.append("FROM osqs_institution");
 I should make space before "from" key work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first version of your query you have specified the `WHERE` clause after the `ORDER BY` which is syntactically wrong.

The second version works in MySQL, but not in Oracle.

In either case you can't get any rows when you use it with a BETWEEN.

Instead try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT full_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY full_name) rn
        FROM osqs_institution
)
SELECT rn, full_name
  FROM qry
WHERE rn BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

If you don't want to use ROW_NUMBER function, then try this:

```
SELECT rn, full_name
  FROM
(
    SELECT full_name, ROWNUM AS rn 
        FROM (SELECT * FROM osqs_institution ORDER BY full_name)
)
WHERE  rn BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Comment: It works thanx, but what " ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY full_name)" means ?

Comment: ROW_NUMBER is an analytic function available in Oracle. It means that Order the records by full_name and then assign a row number for each one.

Comment: @Cybernate - In the second query, I assume you meant `ROWNUM` not `ROWNUMBER`

Comment: Why when executing the statement in java , it cause an exception which is "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" event it works when executing it in oracle?

Comment: @Alaa: Can you post your Java Code?